# Unique URL for profile page using Tomcat - Social Site

Tags: jsp, url, tomcat, redirect, profile

I am making a social networking web app using **Tomcat** and I am having a hard time figuring out how to create a unique user profile URL, so that when users click on another user's name, they get redirected to his profile.
I've done something similar in the past using *PHP* and *htaccess*, but it seems that with *Tomcat* and *jsp*, which I am using now, that is not the case.
Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated as this is vital for what I am working on.